# MediaPlayer datasource issue

Tags: android, media-player

I have a problem with the MediaPlayer. Just when I set the datasource, I get the error:

```
02-22 21:26:10.050: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(7332): setDataSource: outside path in JNI is �x@
```

My device is a Samsum Galaxy Advance and my code:

```
try {
      mediaPlayer.reset();
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaController.show();
      mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the variable audioFile?  Log it to make sure it is what you are expecting. It should be the path (or url) to the file.

Comment: the path /mnt/sdcard/NaturaLocal/muralla_torreVieja_es.mp3 Any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Ernesto Rodriguez, exactly same issue I am facing. If you have found the solution then please share it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the data source path like this and use mediacontroller in this way:

```
String audioFile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
audioFile+="/NaturaLocal/muralla_torreVieja_es.mp3";

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
MediaController mc= new MediaController(mp);
mc.setDataSource(audiofile);
mc.prepare();
mc.start();
```